# Are margin and padding only applied to layout and element respectively?

Tags: html, css, layout, padding, margin

I’m a UX designer and currently working on WYSIWYG editor. I was wondering if this structure (displayed in the image) correct?

If so, are margin and padding only applied to layout and element respectively? If so, there wouldn’t be a scenario where padding is applied to a layout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In each design, each element is considered as a box
And each design is a set of boxes that are placed next to each other.
Each box consists of an interior space and a border and an outer space.
Each box can be spaced from adjacent boxes
This distance is applied to the box with the Margin feature
The Border of each box can be spaced from its contents, which is applied with padding.
Note: All elements can have borders and pads.